# Why was "->" deprecated in F# comprehensions?

Tags: f#

Sometimes in books I see this syntax for list and sequence comprehensions in F#:

```
seq { for i = 0 to System.Int32.MaxValue -> i }
```

This is from [Programming F# by Chris Smith](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596153643), page 80.  In the F# which comes with VS2010, this doesn't compile.  I believe `->` has been deprecated.  (See [Alternative List Comprehension Syntax](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Lists#Alternative_List_Comprehension_Syntax)).  However, `->` can still be used in comprehensions which involve ranges:

```
seq { for c in 'A' .. 'Z' -> c }
```

According to [Expert F# 2.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430224312), page 58, this is because `->` is shorthand for `Seq.map` over a range.

1. Why was the first usage of `->` above deprecated?
2. The current use of `->` seems inconsistent.  Can anyone reconcile this for me?

Answer (score 10):

The `->` construct is supported only in the "simple" sequence expression syntax where you're doing a projection (`Seq.map`) over some data source using the following structure:

```
seq { for <binding> in <input> -> <projection> }
```

The first example you mentioned is using `for .. to ..` which is a different syntactical construct than `for .. in`, but you can rewrite it using the second one (In fact, I almost always use `for .. in` when writing sequence expressions):

```
seq { for i in 0 .. System.Int32.MaxValue -> i }
```

In all other forms of sequence expressions you'll have to use `yield`. In earlier versions of F#, the `->` syntax was equivalent to `yield` (and there was also `->>` which was equivalent to `yield!`). So for example, you was able to write:

```
seq { -> 10              // You need 'yield' here
      ->> [ 1; 2; 3 ] }  // You need 'yield!' here
```

This syntax looks quite odd, so I think that the main reason for making these two deprecated is to keep the language consistent. The same *computation expression* syntax is used in sequence expressions (where `->` makes some sense), but also for other computation types (and you can define your own), where `yield` feels more appropriate (and it also corresponds to `return` in asynchronous workflows or other computation expressions).

The "simple" sequence-specific syntax is still useful, because it saves you some typing (you replace `do yield` with just `->`), but in more complicated cases, you don't save that many characters and I think that the syntax using `->` & `->>` can look a bit cryptic.